# Reading a specific user input from a txt file

Tags: python, readfile

I have a program which let the user input som data which then get drawn on the canvas (like a weekly scheme).
I now want the user to be able to delete or redo an entry (which i will do by a click event), however, my question goes:

How do i read a specific line in my textfile? A sample of a possible textfile:

```
Abe
#0080c0 
February
Friday 
21 
Part delivery 

John 
#ff8000 
July 
Sunday 
21 
Social 

Egon 
#ff80ff 
April 
Thursday 
15 
Work
```

Note that this is a small part of the textfile, ideally it would contain 56 of theese 6-line-clusters.

my code for inserting the text:

```
taskentry = str(tasknameentry.get())
monthentry = str(monthvar.get())
dayentry = str(dayvar.get())
dateentry = str(datevar.get())
activityentry = str(typevar.get())

tasklist = [taskentry, hexstr, monthentry, dayentry, dateentry, activityentry]
taskfile = open('taskfile.txt', 'a')
for word in tasklist:
    taskfile.write('%s \n' % word)
taskfile.write('\n')
taskfile.close()
```

So for the user to be able to redo or delete a "task" i need to read the file and look for a specific task name or something similar, im just not sure how to. I've read through the .write and .read part of my book, looked at the docs and questions here but havent been able to produce a valid solution.

What i need now, so i can move on is just a way to read fx the 6 appending lines when searching for fx John. So i in the future can have a redo or delete event choosen by a click.

In advance, thanks!

Best regards,
Casper

Comment: I suggest using the `fileinput` module.  It has an in place editing option.

Comment: It was not a bad suggestion, reading through the docs :-)

Comment: It is pretty useful. Just thought I would share it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file is not that big, you can read the file into a buffer, modify that buffer and write the buffer back to the file. A quick code snippet would be like:

```
#open the file
f = open('file.txt')
lines = f.readlines()
lineNum = -1

#find the line to modify
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    if line.strip() == "John":
        lineNum = i
        break

if lineNum == -1:
    #Line not found, handle the error..

#modify the buffer with the new data
newtasklist = [taskentry, hexstr, monthentry, dayentry, dateentry, activityentry]
for task in newtasklist:
    lines[lineNum] = task
    lineNum += 1

#or if you want to remove the task list :
lines = lines[:lineNum] + [lineNum + 7:]

# and write everything back
with open('file.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.writelines(lines)
```

Comment: So the new data written is the lines[lineNum] = task, right? :-)

Comment: That is to modify the data in the buffer which is a list of strings, the last step actually writes back to the file :)

Comment: Just a last clerify :-) So it would be something like:
task = #newuserinput
lines[lineNum] = task if im not mistaken?

Comment: newtasklist will be the new task list that you will get from the user.  Then you override the existing task with the new task through that code.

Comment: In that way! Brilliant! Thank you!

Comment: Sorry to bother you again ;-)
Would it be possible if i added 5 dashes (-----) after each entry to take everything in between thoose?

Comment: This code depends on the file structure you have provided, each record is 6 lines and records are separated with a blank line. If you add it with 5 dashes, the file structure will change, thus the code will break.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, i'm not the best at this, but if you scan your entire document and store it into an ArrayList of Strings, you would then be able to delete certain lines, add lines, and modify lines.

After doing that, you can erase your document's information and repaste whats in the ArrayList.

As for reading a specific line, i don't actually think there is a way to read the line using Scanner or FileWriter.

Sorry if this doesn't really help. I am doing my best to help in any way!

Some Example Code Might be:

```
ArrayList<String> taskList = new <String>ArrayList;

File file = new File(<File Name>);
try
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
    while(scan.hasNext())
    {
            taskList.add(scan.next());
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;
}
```

This will create a searchable array of the words which you can then delete and add to as much as you want, then clear your document and re-paste the new information from the array list in it.

Comment: This is not a bad idea at all actually, but i think Faruk's solution was the one i was looking for, cheers for taking you time to reply me :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can make the list in which each entry is a separate line of your txt file by using readlines.
Then you can alter particular enries in this list and use writelines to change the txt file.

```
Tasks=open('taskfile.txt', 'r').readlines()
```

In data you have tasks of each person by name:

```
Data={}
n=0
try:
  while True:
     Data[Tasks[n+n*6]]=Tasks[n+1:n+6]
     n+=1
except:
   pass
```

Then you can change the second task of John by:

```
Data['John'][1]='Football'
```

Comment: So say i wanted to change John's 3rd task into June i would load June into Data and extract that into my list and save it?